# Debian - cannot delete /etc/group- -- "Device or resource busy"

Tags: debian, files, rm, firejail

I can't remove `/etc/group-` -- why not?

```
root@dom:/etc# whoami
root
root@dom:/etc# pwd
/etc
root@dom:/etc# rm -f /etc/group-
rm: cannot remove ‘/etc/group-’: Device or resource busy
root@dom:/etc# fuser -v /etc/group-
root@dom:/etc# mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,relatime,size=10240k,nr_inodes=2040032,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=3280816k,mode=755)
/dev/sde1 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpu,cpuacct)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_cls,net_prio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=22,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /var type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdd1 on /opt type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdc1 on /mediafiles type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb1 on /mediafiles/blurays type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
rpc_pipefs on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1640408k,mode=700)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=1640408k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
root@dom:/etc# uname -a
Linux dom 3.16.0-4-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 3.16.43-2+deb8u2 (2017-06-26) x86_64 

GNU/Linux
root@dom:/etc# lsof +D /etc
COMMAND  PID   USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF     NODE NAME
openvpn 1855 nobody  cwd    DIR   8,65     4096 13634055 /etc/openvpn
jsvc    2070   root    3r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
jsvc    2070   root    4r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
jsvc    2078   root    3r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
jsvc    2078   root    4r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
jsvc    2079   root    3r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
jsvc    2079   root    4r   REG   8,65     1649 13634356 /etc/java-8-openjdk/jvm-amd64.cfg
mc      3538   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
bash    3547   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
mc      5549   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
bash    5551   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
lsof    5928   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
lsof    5929   root  cwd    DIR   8,65    12288 13631489 /etc
root@dom:/etc# ls -l /etc/group-
-rw------- 1 root root 1168 Jul 17 21:53 /etc/group-
root@dom:/etc# ls -l /|grep etc
drwxr-xr-x 153 root root 12288 Jul 17 21:57 etc
root@dom:/etc#
```

Comment: Why anyone would like to delete `/etc/group`?

Comment: @fugitive -- there's a dash at the end

Comment: @fugitive it doesn't really matter is it group or group-, i just wonder why it's busy

Answer (score 1):

Found an answer - it's a kernel bug prior to 3.18 The behavior is caused by firejail:
https://github.com/netblue30/firejail/issues/574

Comment: Pleased to hear you've found the problem. There was no mention of firejail on your question, nor indeed any mention of anything that would suggest it wasn't a vanilla installation on a physical server. Next time please remember to include such detail.

Comment: I cannot list all packages that are running on this machine, sorry. Just tried to find the reason stopping running processes one by one and found that. Maybe it could be useful for somebody else.

Comment: and btw it's a kernel bug, not firejail